# How can i get items of ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my application I should get some `list` from the **server** and I want to show this list.

I've written the code below:

```
private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings;
mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();
cloudChipList.clear();
fullSearchMini_chipCloud.removeAllViews();

for (int i = 0; i < mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length; i++) {

    cloudChipList.add(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);
    if (i >= mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length - 2) {

        fullSearchMini_didYouMeanLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fullSearchMini_chipCloud.addChip(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);
        Log.e("searchKeys", mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);

        fullSearchMini_chipCloud.setChipListener(new ChipListener() {
            @Override
            public void chipSelected(int i) {
                try {
                    Log.e("searchKeys", "new : " + mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void chipDeselected(int i) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I show this data to the user it's correct and show's the data, however, when I click on this item it shows me another item!

**In Logcat it shows me below item :**

```
searchKeys: Recep Ivedik 5
```

**But when I click on this item it shows me another item in logcat :**

```
searchKeys: new : Recep Ivedik 3
```

To show the item and to click it I use this code `mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]`, why in logCat show me another item when click on this item?

Comment: what should do this line? if (i >= mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length - 2)

Comment: @firegloves, I want show just 2 last item. not show all items. JUST 2 last it. can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is due to wrong mixing of arrays.
I've never used ChipCloud, but I think that if you register listeners only for some items of your `mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings` array then the registered array have different indices.

For example if you have a `mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings` of 5 items (0=>1,1=>2,2=>3,3=>4,4=>5) and you register only last two items of it, then registerd ChipListener cosists in an array of only two indices (0=>4,1=>5). As you can see you have 2 arrays with non aligned indices. The `i` that you receive into `public void chipSelected(int i)` is relative to the second array, but you use it to access data from the first array.

I'm not sure that this is the problem, let me know if I have well predicted :)

Try this code:

```
private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings;
        mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();
        cloudChipList.clear();
        fullSearchMini_chipCloud.removeAllViews();

    for (int i = 0; i < mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length; i++) {

        cloudChipList.add(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);

        if (i >= mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length - 2) {
            fullSearchMini_didYouMeanLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
fullSearchMini_didYouMeanLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


        fullSearchMini_chipCloud.addChip(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);
        Log.e("searchKeys", mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);

        fullSearchMini_chipCloud.setChipListener(new ChipListener() {
            @Override
            public void chipSelected(int i) {
                try {
                    Log.e("searchKeys", "new : " + mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void chipDeselected(int i) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: can you send me true code with my above codes? please

Comment: in your code show me all of items. I want show JUST lasted 2 items. NOT ALL ITEMS

Comment: please edit your code, for show just lasted 2 items. please my bro. I really need your help. please

Comment: yes my bro, in your code fixed show item's name. but now show all of items. I want just lasted 2 items

Comment: Ok understood, try now please

Comment: Absolutely not. what you must do is to find a way to get the views added as Chip object and hide them. Start from here https://github.com/fiskurgit/ChipCloud/blob/0f6a3c1e389d92391d2816393bf0259629a674d2/library/src/main/java/fisk/chipcloud/ChipCloud.java